# How do you get to your minecraft folders?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I search up minecraft on folders it won't show anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to get to your AppData folder. This is a "hidden" folder by default in Windows. There are a few ways to get to it.

1. Open the start menu and type %AppData% into the search bar.
2. Open file explorer and click on the top bar, you should be able to enter text into a box. Type into this box C:\Users\WHATEVERYOURUSERNAMEIS\AppData\ and you should obviously replace WHATEVERYOURUSERNAMEIS with your username.
3. Open file options and check the box that says to show hidden files and folders.

Inside of AppData you should see .minecraft. If you plan to make changes/use it often I would recommend creating a shortcut to it somewhere.